# How do I run a terminal command when I press the run code button in visual studio code on linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, love2d

I am running a Love2D project and to use the print method on linux the program has to be run in a terminal, the love2D extension doesnt output the print statements in the output window, the command is this( love "/home/MyName/Lua Code/Project/" ), I have looked through stack-overflow and searching what I want but I got mixed information and I have no clue how to do it, and if it is possible I would like to reroute the output from the terminal into visual studios output window so It doesn't have to open a new terminal window.